# playing a specific interval of a video in mplayer using command line option

Tags: video-processing, mplayer

I am using mplayer to play videos... I wanted to know if there are command line options to play a specific interval of a video in mplayer?
For example, if I want to play a video file from 56 secs for a duration of 3 secs, then what would the command line options be?
I know about the -ss option that will seek to a specific position, but how do I specify the duration that I want to play?
Concretely, if I want a command that plays a video file starting at the beginning of the 56th second and plays 3 seconds of the video (i.e., until the beginning of the 59th sec, or equivalently, the end of the 58th sec.), what would the command look like?

I have been looking at the man page, but no success as yet. Maybe I am missing something.
I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Isn't there an `endpos` switch?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
man mplayer
```

reveals:

```
-ss <time>: Seek to given time position
-endpos <[[hh:]mm:]ss[.ms]|size[b|kb|mb]>: Stop at given time or byte position
```

so you should be able to do what you want by simple using:

```
mplayer -ss 56 -endpos 3
```

Comment: what if I want to stop at a time point counting from the end? For example, I want to play video from 0:15 to T-0:12, where T is a total play time of the video, it can vary.

Answer (score 20):

Using [mpv](https://mpv.io/), a fork of MPlayer:

```
# specify start and length
mpv --start=3:20 --length=10 <file-name>

# specifying end
mpv --start=30 --end=40 <file-name>

# specifying end from end
mpv --start=80 --end=-90 <file-name>
```

More at [mpv manual](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#options-start).

Comment: Thanks . For my file mplayer did not work for endpos. Using mpv worked superb!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop with `loop=inf`, `mpv --start` and `--length/end` suggested by [@qed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24204021/1074998) will stop working, you need:

```
mpv --start=0:56 --ab-loop-a=0:56 --ab-loop-b=0:59 foo.mp4
```

Note:

- `--start` for first time play, then hit `--ab-loop-b` will seek to `--ab-loop-a` time to loop. So `--start` and `--ab-loop-a` need same value.
- `loop=inf` is no longer needed.

Relevant issue ticket [here](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/9010).